# F# Dynamic Eval, Reflection, IL

Tags: reflection, f#, cil

Since I seem to spend 95% of my coding time actually in F#'s FSI, I detoured (see:Distracted) and wanted to write some utility functions.

The particular utility I am interested in is a 'disassemble' (http://www.cons.org/cmucl/doc/reading-disassembly.html) function that can dump the IL for a given function, later on maybe counting instructions, basic static analysis etc, generally this is just distraction heaven. I have already written the code to map the byteArrayIL into MSIL names (almost).

Here is the snippet that is used to get function names from the current module:

```
let dec_c = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(dec_c).GetTypes() 
|> Seq.map (fun x -> x.FullName) //, get_function_instructions x)
```

This works mostly ok, as the x.FullName reflects the actual function name:

```
FSI_0001
<StartupCode$FSI_0001>.$FSI_0001
FSI_0002
FSI_0002+instructions_of_bytes@24
FSI_0002+remove_null_function_body_bytes@32
FSI_0002+remove_null_function_body_bytes@31-1
FSI_0002+resolve_IL_from_bytes@38
FSI_0002+resolve_IL_from_bytes@36-1
FSI_0002+it@49
FSI_0002+it@50-1
<StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002
FSI_0003
FSI_0003+it@49-2
FSI_0003+it@50-3
<StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003
```

So we can easily write a function to filter based on our function name.

Unfortunately (and probably due to my misunderstanding), it seems that not all functions are available in this manner, for example if we define the following simple function then re-run the dump:

```
(* reload FSI *)
let simple_add x = x + 1
(* rerun the function name dumping *)

FSI_0001
<StartupCode$FSI_0001>.$FSI_0001
FSI_0002
FSI_0002+instructions_of_bytes@24
FSI_0002+remove_null_function_body_bytes@32
FSI_0002+remove_null_function_body_bytes@31-1
FSI_0002+resolve_IL_from_bytes@38
FSI_0002+resolve_IL_from_bytes@36-1
FSI_0002+it@50
FSI_0002+it@51-1
<StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002
```

Strangely, there is no presence of 'simple_add' function in the resulting text.

Thoughts:
    1. Maybe the function simple_add isn't realised by reflection until it is seen to be used? Sounds odd.
    2. It could be that one of those "FSI_0002+it" strings is actually our function.

Questions:
    1. Why doesn't the output reflect all the function names?
    2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `<StartupCode$FSI_0001>.$FSI_0001` seems to be `simple_add`.

Comment: I'm guessing this might be because you can define values twice, so instead of the real name, a mock line-based name is used and FSI has a table from label to the latest mock name.

Comment: ah.. that would make sense, but what if you have 2 functions you want to check, or 15, 100000, etc, it will be hard to guess which function it could be,

Comment: I don't think FSI was really designed for debugging and dynamic manipulation :) I do know that FSC generates reasonable names (even lambdas have their parent function's name, in addition to their line number and a unique identifier).

Comment: You are probably right, but it would be a cool feature to hack with!

Comment: @DavidK: Are you aware of Mono.Cecil? It can do everything you have requested - all you have to do is bridge System.Reflection over to Mono.Cecil.

Comment: @JohannesRudolph, yes however mono cecil is a bit over the top for this, i dont need actual dynamic compilation (post title may have been misleading), just inspection of the bytecode for static analysis purposes and general tinkering. If I were writing a library \ using this in production, i would no doubt use cecil.

Comment: @DavidK: The guys behind ILSpy have written their tooling around Mono.Cecil too for the same purposes. General tinkering is a great reason to write this stuff yourself though, enjoy :-)

Comment: @JohannesRudolph you most certainly have a good point, and I have most certainly detoured too much! http://codepad.org/54uGF5dr, its fun though :) edit: and now I have gained appreciation for the pain in the butt it is, full steam ahead to Cecil!

Answer (score 3):

I think I have slept (half slept) on the answer, I was going about it wrong, there is no need to have a list of per function string names...

```
let get_function_instructions (mb : System.Type) = 
  mb.GetMethods() 
  |> Seq.map ...

let find_func_print_instructions f =
  f.GetType()
  |> get_function_instructions 
  |> print_instruction_text
```